# Syntax to remove interaction terms of one variable with all other variables in the dataset

Tags: r

Suppose I have 6 independent variables, x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6. Suppose I want to fit a model with all main effects and the two terms interactions. Then my syntax will be:

```
lm(y~.+.^2, data=d)
```

x1  is actually ID variable. So if I want to discard the main effect, I can write `lm(y~.+-x1+.^2, data=d)`

But how can I write the syntax to remove the interaction terms having id (x1 variable) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```r
lm(y ~ . + (. - x1) ^ 2, data = d)
```

which leads to

```
(Intercept)
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
x6
x2:x3
x2:x4
x2:x5
x2:x6
x3:x4
x3:x5
x3:x6
x4:x5
x4:x6
x5:x6
```